# Getting an error in my code how to fix it?

Tags: java, methods, collections, linked-list

I have the following code:

```
public static void poistaKaikki32(LinkedList L1, Collection L2) {
        LinkedList<Integer> temp = new LinkedList<>();
        HashSet<Integer> L2Set = new HashSet<>(L2); 

        // first filter elements into temp
        while (L1.size() > 0) { // n loops
            int v = L1.removeFirst(); <--- getting error cannot convert object to int
            if (!L2Set.contains(v)) { 
                temp.addLast(v);      
            }
        }

        // add filtered values back to L1
        while (temp.size() > 0) {    
            L1.addLast(temp.removeFirst()); 
        }


    }
```

I keep getting an error on int v = L1.removeFirst();. How would i fix this, without using casts.

Comment: What is return type of `removeFirst()` ?

Comment: If the parameter `L1` is a `LinkedList`  containing `Integer`s, then declare it as `LinkedList<Integer> L1`; if you can't do that due to negative impact on calling code, you'll have to use an `(Integer)` cast.

Comment: And: learn about java naming conventions. Variable/parameter names go camelCase. And: use **meaningful** that tell human readers what is going on. L1 has no meaning and tells nothing.

Comment: Yeah, @luk2302, a cast isn't optimal; but what to do if there's a ton of stuff calling this thing with raw `List`s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

argument to method is of raw type thats why when you do a get operation on it you get an object type .to make this work either TYPECAST it while doing a get operation using
  `Integer v = (Integer)L1.removeFirst();`

or change the method parameter type  `LinkedList L1` to `LinkedList<Integer> L1`

but best way to do it is second one change the parameter type

Answer (score 1):

Please try

```
Integer v = (Integer)L1.removeFirst();
```

Comment: well, it "fixes" the compiler error by basically ignoring it. This is not a proper answer. Change the type of `L1` instead.

Comment: @luk2302 Actually you are right  `public static void poistaKaikki32(LinkedList<Integer> L1, Collection<Integer> L2) {`